# What are the values of a,b and c in this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

> Determine the constants $a,b,c$ so that the number $-1$ would be a root of order $2$ of the polynomial $P$ such that $P(x)=(3a+b)x^4+(c-2a)x^3-(2b+c)x+2a+2b+c$

So, I have found two equations in 3 unknwons and I still need one more in order to solve it.

$P(-1)=0.... 7a+5b-c=0$

$P'(-1)=0.... -18a-6b+2c=0$

I'm in Rolle's theorem and MVT lesson and I think this question is an application of the theorems (under the titles: [Expansion of a plynomial in terms of the powers of $(x-a)$] and [A root of order p of a polynomial]) 《 if it might help》
Any type of hints please :)

Comment: I don't think there is another equation. You need $P(-1)=0$ and $P'(-1)=0$. You also need $P''(-1)\neq 0$, if you interpret the question to mean that $-1$ is a root of order exactly $2$, but that isn't enough to function a third equation, I think.It looks like an incomplete question.

Comment: Mmmm...what do you think then? -1 should be a ropt of order 3? In order for the problem to be solved? Because my friends also didn't know it...i'll check the answer on Monday and inform you....thanks alot

Comment: if $a, b, c$ is a solution, so is $ka, kb, kc$, so you will always have a degree of freedom remaining.  You can express $a, b$ in terms of $c$ or maybe the question is asking for a monic polynomial?

Comment: I actually expressed a and b in terms of c...thank uuu :)